# "Has this experience been enjoyable for you?" How to convert it into active voice?

Tags: active-voice

I want to convert the following passive voice into active voice
"Has this experience been enjoyable for you?"

How can I convert it into active voice?

Answer (score 2):

The original sentence is **not** passive. It is a copular sentence, employing the adjective *enjoyable*.

A passive version would be *Has the experience been enjoyed by you?* - a question so stilted that I find it hard to imagine an English speaker actually saying it.

Answer (score -1):

"Have you enjoyed this experience?"